# Which one is correct, with or without a comma?

Tags: punctuation

(1) It is possible to acquire through long experience some appreciation of the point of view of the laboratory scientist, some understanding of his methods, and the way he conceives a problem.

(2) It is possible to acquire through long experience some appreciation of the point of view of the laboratory scientist, some understanding of his methods and the way he conceives a problem.

Which sentence has the connotation that the writer might have plagiarized or taken (with or without permission) the scientist's way of discovering problems, which is of hypothesis (the one with a comma or the one without a comma after the phrase his methods)?
Could you help me clarify it?   Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what plagiarism has to do with your example. For sttylistic reasons I would ***not*** include the comma - but if you wanted to have it there I'd suggest repeating the preposition: *...some understanding of his methods, and **of** the way he [blah blah]*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer.  It helped me a lot.

Comment: It's a long (*unnecessarily* long, imho) sentence, and all you're really doing is repeating yourself anyway. I don't see much difference between *some appreciation of his X* and *some understanding of his X*, and in practice your three values for X *(his point of view, his methods, the way he conceives a problem)* effectively all refer to the same thing. On purely stylistic grounds I'd start with the most important element of what you're trying to convey *(through long experience)*, but I think that's Off Topic "writing advice" here on ELL.